# No tidy method for objects of class LiblineaR

Tags: r, tidymodels

I have fitted text data based on regression and LiblineaR engine. And I want to `tidy()` my results. I have also installed the dev version of `broom`.
But I always get an error.  `ERROR: No tidy method for objects of class LiblineaR`

```
> svm_fit %>%
+   pull_workflow_fit() %>%
+   tidy()
ERROR: No tidy method for objects of class LiblineaR
```

Comment: The error indiocates that the authors of `broom` haven't written a `tidy()` function for the `LiblineaR` class.  You can ask them to do it, you can ask the authors of the package that creates `LiblineaR` objects, or you can write one yourself.  It shouldn't be difficult.  Without knowing your input data and your desired output, it's difficult to give you more concrete advice.

Comment: I assume you are working through the code in smltar.com. We wrote tidy.LiblineaR
https://github.com/EmilHvitfeldt/smltar/blob/master/_common.R#L143-L149, it will be added soon to the appropriate package before the book is released

Comment: yes that is correct. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

We just merged in support for the `tidy()` method for parsnip models fitted with the LiblineaR engine, so if you install from GitHub, you should be able to have this feature now:

```r
devtools::install_github("tidymodels/parsnip")
```

Here is a demo of how it works:

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip

data(two_class_dat, package = "modeldata")
example_split <- initial_split(two_class_dat, prop = 0.99)
example_train <- training(example_split)
example_test  <-  testing(example_split)

rec <- recipe(Class ~ ., data = example_train) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

spec1 <- svm_linear() %>%
  set_engine("LiblineaR") %>%
  set_mode("classification")

spec2 <- logistic_reg(penalty = 0.1, mixture = 1) %>%
  set_engine("LiblineaR") %>%
  set_mode("classification")

wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(rec)

wf %>%
  add_model(spec1) %>% 
  fit(example_train) %>%
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   term  estimate
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 A        0.361
#> 2 B       -0.966
#> 3 Bias     0.113

wf %>%
  add_model(spec2) %>% 
  fit(example_train) %>%
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   term  estimate
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 A        1.06 
#> 2 B       -2.76 
#> 3 Bias     0.329

svm_linear() %>%
  set_engine("LiblineaR") %>%
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  fit(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) %>% 
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 11 x 2
#>    term  estimate
#>    <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1 cyl    0.141  
#>  2 disp  -0.0380 
#>  3 hp     0.0415 
#>  4 drat   0.226  
#>  5 wt     0.0757 
#>  6 qsec   1.06   
#>  7 vs     0.0648 
#>  8 am     0.0479 
#>  9 gear   0.219  
#> 10 carb   0.00861
#> 11 Bias   0.0525
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>